# Multiplying a vector and a matrix

Tags: java

My goal is to multiply matrix a and vector vec:

```
public static int[] vectorProduct(int[][] a, int[] x){
    if(x.length != a[0].length)
        throw new RuntimeException("Illegal matrix dimensions.");
    int [] y = new int[a.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<y.length;i++){
        int sum=0;
        for(int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++){
            sum+= a[i][j] * x[j];
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

My main class looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int [][] d = { {1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
    int [] vec = { 1,1,1 };

    System.out.println("Vector product of matrix A and vecor x: ");
    int[] v = MatMath.vectorProduct(d, vec);
    print(v);
}
```

I'm supposed to get [3,6,9] but i'm getting [0,0,0] as my output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you never do anything with the variable `sum`. You should probably be putting it in your `y` array since you're returning it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never insert anything to `y` array

```
int [] y = new int[a.length];
for(int i = 0 ; i < y.length ; i++){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < a[0].length ; j++){
        sum += a[i][j] * x[j];          
    }
    y[i] = sum;
}
return y;
```

Comment: when i fix it that way, I get [6,6,6] which is not the correct vector. The correct vector is [3,6,9]. hmm

Comment: @onepunchman You are summing the rows in `a`. To sum the columns switch `i` and `j` in `a[i][j]` `sum += a[j][i] * x[j];`

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are not at all assigning any value to `int array y` .

> I'm supposed to get [3,6,9] but i'm getting [0,0,0] as my output

Yeah , because by default all elements of

```
 int
```

array are being assinged to `0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign values to the indexes of the array `y` -

```
for(int i = 0; i<y.length;i++){
    int sum=0;
    for(int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++){
        sum+= a[i][j] * x[j];
    }
    y[i] =sum; //this should help you assign the values
}
```